# Interval of Validity for Solutions of a Separable ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, initial-value-problems

I've been asked to find solutions to the separable ODE given by $$(t^2-12t+27)\frac{dy}{dt}=y,\qquad y(6)=1.$$ and to find the interval on which the solution is valid. What I have so far is \begin{align*}
(t^2-12t+27)\frac{dy}{dt}&=y \\
\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dt}&=\frac{1}{t^2-12t+27} \\
\int\frac{1}{y}dy&=\int\frac{1}{t^2-12t+27}dt \\
\log|y|&=\frac{1}{6}\log|t-9|-\frac{1}{6}\log|t-3|+C.
\end{align*} After using the initial value and a bit of calculation, I got that $C=0$. Carrying on, \begin{align*}
\log|y|&=\frac{1}{6}\log\left|\frac{t-9}{t-3}\right| \\
y&=\left(\frac{t-9}{t-3}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}. 
\end{align*} After doing all this, I got that the interval of validity should be $t\geq9$, but I got the answer incorrect after putting it into the system.

I just want to know where and why I went wrong.  Even after keeping the absolute value, the interval of validity is for all $t\neq3$, and still got it wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your works seems fine. The solution is required to exist around $t=6$, as that's where you have one of your conditions. So one reasonable answer would be $3<t<9$.

Comment: I forgot about how the initial condition affects the absolute values.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your interval needs to contain the initial point at $t=6$. This also means that you have to solve the absolute values in a form that is valid at $t=6$, giving
\begin{align*}
y&=\left(\frac{9-t}{t-3}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}, 
\end{align*}
that the interval of validity is $3<t<9$.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about how the initial condition would affect the absolute values. Thank you so much.  Also, i think it should be $3<t<9$.